# IIS 7 Enabling 32-bit Applications

Tags: iis-7

Has anyone observed any performance degradation if an IIS7 application pool is configured to use the "Enable 32-bit Applications" setting?

Any articles on this topic also will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest performance boost is going to be through RAM utilization.  Might not be as noticeable with low user loads, but under high utilization if the worker process is able to use more memory at once.  If an application requires a lot of memory, 64-bit worker processes should perform better.

Here is one article that talks about it:  http://petesbloggerama.blogspot.com/2006/04/iis-aspnet-and-64-bit-performance.html